# Employ, adopt, use, apply

Tags: difference, synonyms

What is the difference between these words. I don't mean **employ** as *"find somebody for a job"* and **adopt** as *"to get an orphan"*. I mean the meaning similar to **use**.

Comment: Have you looked at the words in one or more dictionaries, and compared the definitions?

Comment: Very roughly, you _use_ or _employ_ a tool or a method, you _adopt_ a method or a plan, you _apply_ a method.

Comment: @KateBunting I 99% agree with you, except that I think you can *apply* a tool if you literally mean "apply to the surface of", e.g. "apply ointment to your eye" or "how to apply a file to a part to remove burrs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Employ*, *use*, and *apply* are all very similar in meaning: they all basically mean *use*.

*Adopt* is the only one that is a little different in meaning: it means something like "to choose as a *new* method for regular use".

So, for example,

We **employed** the Poldolsky method = We used the Podolsky method.

We **adopted** the Podolsky method = We were not using the Podolsky method before, but we started using it regularly.